# Remove Records with more than 30 of the same value

Tags: awk, csv

I have a large CSV, and want to remove the records that have the same FirstName field ($8), MiddleName field ($9) and LastName field ($10) if there is more than 30 instances of it.

```
TYPE|10007|44|Not Available||||CHRISTINE||HEINICKE|||49588|2014-09-15|34
TYPE|1009|44|Not Available||||ELIZABETH||SELIGMAN|||34688|2006-02-12|69
TYPE|102004|44|Not Available||||JANET||OCHS|||11988|2014-09-15|1022
TYPE|1000005|44|Not Available||||KIMBERLY||YOUNG|||1988|2016-10-04|1082
```

This is what I have so far:

```
awk -F"|" '++seen[tolower($8 || $9 || $10)] <= 30' foo.csv > newFoo.csv
```

Comment: We need to know the definition of "30 instances".  For example, lines that do have 50 instances of FirstName Only ($8) but instances of Middle Name ($9) and / or Last Name ($10) are bellow 30, should be removed or should be kept ? Maybe you want to remove lines with more than 30 instances of the Combination "$8 AND $9 AND $10" ?

Comment: Also, do you want to remove all instances (including the first 30) or just those after the first 30?   This makes a huge difference in how the problem can/should be approached and how much memory will be consumed while running.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to create an example that's, say, 10 lines long where you want to remove lines that there's more than, say, 3 instances of, i.e. create a **minimal** example that demonstrates your problem and we can copy/paste to test a potential solution against. You can tweak the answer later to change 3 to 30 to run on your real data.

Comment: Don't name an array that keeps a count `seen` as that obfuscates your code, name it `count` (or even better something more specific like `numKeys` ) instead. The array name `seen` is idiomatically **ONLY** used to separate the first time an index has been seen from subsequent times so you can write code like `if ( !seen[$0]++ ) foo` to do something the first time the index appeared or `if ( seen[$0]++ ) bar` to do something every subsequent time. If you need to do anything with a specific number of occurrences of an index then use `if ( ++count[$0] == 30 ) foo`or similar instead.

Answer (score 2):

I will be assuming that we're dealing with a "simple CSV" file, i.e., one that does not contain fields with embedded delimiters or embedded newlines.

Removing the instances of the entries that occur after seeing 30 of them:

```bsh
awk -F '|' 'count[$8,$9,$10]++ < 30' file
```

Removing also the first 30 instances of those entries, we can use something like the above for counting and then parse the file a second time for filtering and outputting:

```bsh
awk -F '|' '!output { ++count[$8,$9,$10]; next } count[$8,$9,$10] <= 30' file output=1 file
```

I'm mentioning the file twice in the list of arguments and setting the variable `output` to `1` in-between.  This would switch the code from "counting mode" (the first block in the code) to "filtering and output mode" (the test after the first block).

If you need to lower-case the key that you use, I would suggest calculating it separately first, for readability:

```bsh
awk -F '|' '
    { key = tolower($8) SUBSEP tolower($9) SUBSEP tolower($10) }
    count[key]++ < 30' file
```

```bsh
awk -F '|' '
    { key = tolower($8) SUBSEP tolower($9) SUBSEP tolower($10) }
    !output { ++count[key]; next }
    count[key] <= 30' file output=1 file
```

The value of `SUBSEP` is the special delimiter that `awk` inserts between the values when you use them as a comma-delimited key as is done in the two first snippets of code in this answer.

Comment: By the way, switching from 1st code block to second code block, seems possible with the simplier `NR==FNR`

Comment: @GeorgeVasiliou  I gave up on that idiom when it bit me hard: one day, the first file happened to be empty (legitimately), and the code tried to store the second (huge) file in a look-up array intended for the first file.

Comment: @Paul_Pedant though definitely something to consider in general, the first file being empty usually isn't a concern when parsing the same file twice.

Comment: @GeorgeVasiliou I've started to opt for doing it this way instead as it makes for slightly less obfuscated `awk` code, IMO.  The variable can be called something that is self-documenting and it makes it clearer what's going on in the code. The only downside is the "magic" whereby `awk` executes an assignment to a variable picked from the command line arguments.

Comment: It is too bad that the GNU awk variable `ARGIND` isn't defined by POSIX or we could all just use `ARGIND == 1` instead of `NR==FNR` or `FILENAME=ARGV[1]` or `output==0` to identify the first file without any caveats.

Answer (score 2):

This may be what you're trying to do reading the input file twice, assuming the input is stored in a file rather than coming from a pipe:

```
awk -F'|' '
    { name = tolower($8 FS $9 FS $10) }
    NR==FNR { nameCnts[name]++; next }
    nameCnts[name] <= 30
' file file
```

or storing the file contents in an array and so able to work from piped input as well as a file:

```
awk -F'|' '
    {
        name = tolower($8 FS $9 FS $10)
        nameCnts[name]++
        recs[NR] = $0
        names[NR] = name
    }
    END {
        for ( recNr=1; recNr<=NR; recNr++ ) {
            name = names[recNr]
            if ( nameCnts[name] <= 30 ) {
                print recs[recNr]
            }
         }
    }
' file
```

or, probably most efficiently for a large file while also able to work from piped input or a file, use the DSU (Decorate/Sort/Undecorate) idiom:

```
awk '
    BEGIN { FS=OFS="|" }
    { print tolower($8 FS $9 FS $10), $0 }
' file |
sort -t'|' -k1,3 |
awk -F '|' '
    {
        name = $1 FS $2 FS $3
        sub(/([^|]*\|){3}/,"")
    }
    name != prev {
        if ( cnt <= 30 ) printf "%s", buf
        buf = ""
        cnt = 0
        prev = name
    }
    {
        buf = buf $0 ORS
        cnt++
    }
    END  { if ( cnt <= 30 ) printf "%s", buf }
'
```

That last script won't retain the input order. If you care about that an additional sort key of the original line number can be added for a final sort back to the original order.

All of the above will work using any awk, they can be implemented a bit more briefly in GNU awk but IMHO it's not worth the loss of portability in this case.